# (window).resize выполнение сразу после обновления

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том что скрипт выполняется только после того когда я поменяю размер окна (либо увеличю/уменьшу масштаб) - как сделать так чтобы скрипт выполнялся сразу же после обновления страницы. Вроде ясно объяснил.

```js
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth < 1290) {
        console.log("windows size < 1290");
    }
    else {
        
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// определение обработчика resize
$(window).resize(function(){
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if(windowWidth < 1290) {
    console.log("window size < 1290");
  } else {
    console.log("window size >= 1290");
  }
});

// вызов события resize после загрузки страницы
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: windowWidth где указывать?

Comment: не понял. Я просто не стал копировать Ваш код внутри обработчика `resize`.

Comment: Тупанул, спасибо. То что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы же проверяете `WIDTH` во время `.resize()`... если хотите чтобы код всегда работал, просто вставьте

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth < 1290) {
    console.log("windows size < 1290");
}
});
```

Comment: не работает, ничего не поменялось

Comment: вы наверно вставляете код без document ready, я изменил свой ответ